# Cant display json data on the page using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I have create a php file that generates json data.  As shown below but it does not seem to return any data.

When i try to get data.status i get an undefined error.  it seems to be connecting to the file no problem as previously i have coded an alert which drags back all the data but i cant seem to get a specific value.

Below i have trying to retrieve the status: ok value.

Json Data:

```
{"status":"ok","Results":{"SiteId":"1","SiteCode":"RWP50","DateCreated":"2019-09-25 09:14:23","DateClosed":null}}
```

Ajax Code

```
$('#ddlsite').change(function () {
    var SiteCode = $('#ddlsite').val();
    alert(SiteCode);

    $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'GetSites.php',
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success:function(data){ 
                alert(data.status);
                if(status == "ok"){
                alert('It Worked'); 
            }else{
            alert('It Failed');
        }   
    }
});
});
```

PHP File

```
<?php
// if(!empty($_POST['SiteCode'])){
    $data = array();

// Create connection
include 'connecting_test.php'; 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Site";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    // while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $SiteData = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $data['status'] = 'ok';
        $data['Results'] = $SiteData;
    // }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo json_encode($data);

$conn->close();
// }else {
    // echo "hello";
// }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to update your ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'xhr.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success:function(data){ 
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data.status == "ok"){
                alert('It Worked'); 
            }
            else{
                alert('It Failed');
            }   
        }
});
```

Because you need to parse json which are return from php file

Comment: Ankit, Thanks very much for your help.  This works.

Answer (score -1):

I assume your ajax api call is working fine, and returns correctly, as the datatype is json, 
So the alert should work perfectly but the if statement 
if(status == "ok") can't find the reference of variable status. It should be data.status if it's not declared somewhere else then type error will be thrown...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  Yes i am displaying the json data on the screen.  i have changed the if statement to status.data, and in the alert i have also put status.data but i am getting an undefined alert back.

Comment: Hi @Stu , When you provide `dataType: 'json' ` in ajax call the returned data will be automatically parsed by jQuery base on dataType. Its a bad practice to parse it again. There was a small typo in your ajax call settings. Just missed that one earlier. Just change the key `datatype: 'json'` into `dataType:'json'` and it will work without parse. JSON keys are case sensitive.

Don't know why its down voted anyways. 
Just see the reference page of for more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Hi @KdCoder, thanks for the response I have made the amendents and works as expected. :-)